# Prove that the Bernstein polynomials converge uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

**The problem**

Define the Bernstein polynomial of $f$ by

$$B_nf(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n\binom n i x^i(1-x)^{n-i} f(i/n)$$

Prove without the use of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|B_nf - f| = 0$ where $f$ is any continuous function on $[0,1]$.

Hint: For all $\varepsilon>0$ there is a constant $\alpha$, dependent only only $f$ and $\varepsilon$, such that for all $x,y\in[0,1]$ we have

$$ |f(x)-f(y)| < \varepsilon + \alpha M(x-y)^2 $$

where $M=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$.

---

**My attempt**

We have that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$, and so is $B_nf$.  So if we let $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$.  We could further have that $|B_nf(x)-B_nf(y)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$ if we wanted to -- I'm not sure of the value of this, but it can't hurt to have it.

Also,

$$ \sup_{x\in[0,1]} |B_nf(x) - f(x)| \le \sup_{x\in[0,1]} (|B_n f(x)|+|f(x)|) \le \sup_{x\in[0,1]}(B_n|f(x)|+|f(x)|) $$

I don't know if that's of any value either.

I am especially struggling to see the relevance of the hint.  I've found the value of $\alpha$ and I doubt its exact definition is relevant to this problem.

Comment: In $|(B_nf)(x)-f(x)|$ turn the $f(x)$ into $\sum \binom{n}{i}x^i(1-x)^{n-i}f(x)$. Then separate the terms into those with $i/n$ close to $x$ and those far. The terms where $i/n$ is close to $x$ bound using the uniform continuity. For the other terms use [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) or the hint.